# How to Enter a Column of Data in Winforms Using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Winform App where I want a user to be able to enter some stock corrections against a list of products which will in turn create a database record for each of those corrections.

Using a combobox, I got it so each item would have to be selected in turn. It works great, but is not very user friendly. Ideally, I'd like a list of products with an empty column to enter the corrections, click submit and ya done.

I looked at using a datagrdiview. I can generate the list of products, but I've no idea on how to create the 'entry column'.

Any suggestions on the path to take?

Cheers,
Numb

**EDIT**

Here is a mock up of what I would like to do to make it as clear as possible without showing code...

[image: sample of what I'd like]

Comment: please paste code or screen shot of your UI. Not getting exactly what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Do you want to do these things in grid only?

Comment: Please reply quickly, because when you asks question , we take some efforts on it. so plz have some respect.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any code as I don't know what the right approach is hence the question. The code I do have is using a combobox to select each product in turn which isn't relevant. I think I've responded to over 90% of any questions I've asked in my time here and always thanked someone for their help so I think I've proved myself on the respect front!

Comment: may be i am within 10%, because as i can see you have replied after an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use a ”Submit” button to save a new stock correction, then
approach will be:

-Create a datagridview with products names and empty cell for stock correction

-After ”Submit” button was clicked read ”Correction” columns values, if value exists update database…

Here how you can do it:

Create a datagridview in designer `dgvProductCorrections`,
then create with designer a two columns in this datagridview 
`dgvProductCorrection_Product` and `dgvProductCorrection_Correction`. 
Put this(or your) columns names in Column .Name property

Then, I assume that you have a class Product where exists a property .Name,
you will need to put a name of this property(in my example will be Name) in .DataProperty of column

Above can be done with designer or in code(Constructor)

Adding a list products `List<Product> lstProducts;` in datagridview will be as:

```
dgvProductCorrections.DataSource = lstProducts; //(this may be in Form_Load)
```

Rememeber before adding a list set a datagridview property `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False`

```
dgvProductCorrections.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

in `Button_Click` event handler of your Submit button put a code where you loopin through a all rows and reading a correction values. After you can update a database with those values

```
//Code in Button_Click
{   
    foreach(DataGridVewRow dgvr in dgvProductCorrections.Rows)
    {
        Decimal fCorrection;
        //Check if value exists and it can be used. Add own other checks
        if(dgvr.Cells(this. dgvProductCorrection_Correction.Name).Value != null &&  Decimal.TryParse(dgvr.Cells(this.dgvProductCorrection_Correction.Name).Value.ToString(), fCorrection) = True)
        {
         //Here you can put a update code, or save a correction in list and then update all by one update call
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat Thanks again :-)